# Airflow email_on_failure not finding SMTP connection information

Tags: airflow, smtplib

I have Airflow 2.2.4 running in AWS EKS, deployed with the official Helm chart (version 1.6.0).  I am trying to set up email notifications upon DAG failure.  I have this section in my `values` file:

```
config:
  smtp:
    smtp_host: "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp_starttls: "True"
    smtp_ssl: "False"
    smtp_mail_from: "my.address@gmail.com"
    smtp_port: 587
```

I have also configured Airflow to use AWS Secrets Manager as the backend, so secrets in Secrets Manager prefixed with, e.g., `airflow/connections` become Airflow connections.

I have created an AWS Secrets Manager secret named `airflow/connections/smtp_default` and containing:

```
{
  "login": "my.address@gmail.com",
  "password": "blahblahblah"
}
```

I can confirm that Airflow is aware of this connection by `exec`ing into the scheduler pod and running `airflow connections get smtp_default`.

The secret is structured the way it is because the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.2.4/airflow/utils/email.py#L194-L196) suggests that's how it should be done.  Yet, I see this:

```
[2023-06-10, 16:10:58 UTC] {configuration.py:381} WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
[2023-06-10, 16:10:58 UTC] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2023-06-10, 16:11:08 UTC] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 2
[2023-06-10, 16:11:18 UTC] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 3
[2023-06-10, 16:11:28 UTC] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 4
[2023-06-10, 16:11:38 UTC] {email.py:214} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 5
[2023-06-10, 16:11:48 UTC] {configuration.py:381} WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
...
...
```

Am I misreading the source code?  Is there something else that could be the cause of this that I can't think of?

*Edit:*  It doesn't appear that Airflow is correctly parsing the AWS Secrets Manager secret:

```
>>> from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook
>>> conn = BaseHook.get_connection("smtp_default")
>>> conn.login is None
True
>>> conn.password is None
True
>>> # Somehow it's shoving part of the secret into the single field conn.schema
>>> conn.schema
'  "login": "my.address@gmail.com",  "password": "blahblahblah"}'
```

But this seems to contradict the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/secrets-backends/aws-secrets-manager.html#storing-a-connection-as-a-json) for the Secrets Manager backend; namely, the example they provide:

> As an example, if you have set connections_prefix as airflow/connections, then for a connection id of smtp_default, you would want to store your connection at airflow/connections/smtp_default. This can be done through the AWS web console or through Amazon CLI as shown below:

```
aws secretsmanager put-secret-value \
    --secret-id airflow/connections/smtp_default \
    --secret-string '{"login": "nice_user", "password": "this_is_the_password", "host": "ec2.8399.com", "port": "999"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Amazon provider.  I don't know which release did it, but upgrading to Airflow 2.6.0 fixed the issue.